# Is it possible to have UIpageviewcontroller and UItableview on the same screen in ios?

Tags: uitableview, delegates, uipageviewcontroller

i m new to iphone development i m doing an application where i want a uipageviewcontroller to display company images and below that i need a tableview to display a list like services,company profile etc..Issue i m facing here is for UIpageviewcontroller it has to make a link with file owner view and for tableview also it has to link with file owner view but both cannot be possible at the same time because there was only one view controller.so how i need to implement this?

Any suggestions please

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Slightly modified approach: Since you want to mix multiple views on the "same page" (which generally should mean within a single parent UIViewController), you do not want a UIPageViewController and a UITableViewController since each of these wants to own the entire screen.   Instead, you want a UIScrollView + UIPageControl to simulate the UIPageViewController, and a UITableView, all within a single UIViewController.  These will be sub-views of your UIViewController's view and properties within your UIViewController's class.  You then hook up the delegate methods of the UIScrollView, UIPageControl, and UITableView (datasource and delegate) to methods within your UIViewController class implementation.

Comment: here i m adding only images to the pageview so is it necessary to create viewcontroller for each page to display the image?????

Comment: I've done this before: use a UIScrollView with a UIPageControl, and just place images within your UIScrollView.   My original suggestion of using a UIPageView was inaccurate, there is no such thing.